# error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'NvPhysicalGpuHandle'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to add Nvidia API into kodi for HDR switching.
I don't have much knowledge of code, I'm trying to adapt a project HDR Switcher into kodi functions.

When compiling the HDR Switcher into an exe with visual studio it works and triggers HDR. 
Now I need to make it work with kodi for seamless HDR pasthrough playback.

This uses the NVidia private APIs.

Please help this will be valuable for many users if it gets implemented.

The error:
error C2664: 'NvAPI_St
atus NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds(NvPhysicalGpuHandle,NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS *,NvU32 *,NvU32)': cannot convert argument
1 from 'NvPhysicalGpuHandle [64]' to 'NvPhysicalGpuHandle'

```
#include "WinRenderer.h"
#include "RenderCapture.h"
#include "RenderFactory.h"
#include "RenderFlags.h"
#include "rendering/dx/RenderContext.h"
#include "settings/Settings.h"
#include "settings/SettingsComponent.h"
#include "utils/log.h"
#include "windows/RendererDXVA.h"
#include "windows/RendererSoftware.h"
#include "windows/RendererShaders.h"
#include "windowing/GraphicContext.h"
#include "windowing/WinSystem.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "DeviceManager.h"
#include "nvapi.h"
#include "uhdDisplay.h"


struct render_details
{
  using map = std::map<RenderMethod, int>;
  using weights_fn = std::function<void(map&, const VideoPicture&)>;
  using create_fn = std::function<CRendererBase*(CVideoSettings&)>;

  RenderMethod method;
  std::string name;
  create_fn create;
  weights_fn weights;

  template<class T>
  constexpr static render_details get(RenderMethod method, const std::string& name)
  {
    return { method, name, T::Create, T::GetWeight };
  }
};

static std::vector<render_details> RenderMethodDetails =
{
  render_details::get<CRendererSoftware>(RENDER_SW, "Software"),
  render_details::get<CRendererShaders>(RENDER_PS, "Pixel Shaders"),
  render_details::get<CRendererDXVA>(RENDER_DXVA, "DXVA"),
};

CBaseRenderer* CWinRenderer::Create(CVideoBuffer*)
{
  return new CWinRenderer();
}

bool CWinRenderer::Register()
{
  VIDEOPLAYER::CRendererFactory::RegisterRenderer("default", Create);
  return true;
}

CWinRenderer::CWinRenderer()
{
  m_format = AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
  PreInit();
}

CWinRenderer::~CWinRenderer()
{
  CWinRenderer::UnInit();
}

CRendererBase* CWinRenderer::SelectRenderer(const VideoPicture& picture)
{
  int iRequestedMethod = CServiceBroker::GetSettingsComponent()->GetSettings()->GetInt(CSettings::SETTING_VIDEOPLAYER_RENDERMETHOD);
  CLog::LogF(LOGDEBUG, "requested render method: %d", iRequestedMethod);

  std::map<RenderMethod, int> weights;
  for (auto& details : RenderMethodDetails)
    details.weights(weights, picture);

  RenderMethod method;
  switch (iRequestedMethod)
  {
  case RENDER_METHOD_SOFTWARE:
    if (weights[RENDER_SW])
    {
      method = RENDER_SW;
      break;
    }
    // fallback to PS
  case RENDER_METHOD_D3D_PS:
    if (weights[RENDER_PS])
    {
      method = RENDER_PS;
      break;
    }
    //fallback to DXVA
  case RENDER_METHOD_DXVA:
    if (weights[RENDER_DXVA])
    {
      method = RENDER_DXVA;
      break;
    }
    // fallback to AUTO
  case RENDER_METHOD_AUTO:
  default:
  {
    const auto it = std::max_element(weights.begin(), weights.end(),
      [](auto& w1, auto& w2) { return w1.second < w2.second; });

    if (it != weights.end())
    {
      method = it->first;
      break;
    }

    // there is no elements in weights, so no renderer which supports incoming video buffer
    CLog::LogF(LOGERROR, "unable to select render method for video buffer");
    return nullptr;
  }
  }

  const auto it = std::find_if(RenderMethodDetails.begin(), RenderMethodDetails.end(),
    [method](render_details& d) { return d.method == method; });

  if (it != RenderMethodDetails.end())
  {
    CLog::LogF(LOGDEBUG, "selected render method: {}", it->name);
    return it->create(m_videoSettings);
  }

  // something goes really wrong
  return nullptr;
}

CRect CWinRenderer::GetScreenRect() const
{
  CRect screenRect(0.f, 0.f,
    static_cast<float>(CServiceBroker::GetWinSystem()->GetGfxContext().GetWidth()),
    static_cast<float>(CServiceBroker::GetWinSystem()->GetGfxContext().GetHeight()));

  switch (CServiceBroker::GetWinSystem()->GetGfxContext().GetStereoMode())
  {
  case RENDER_STEREO_MODE_SPLIT_HORIZONTAL:
    screenRect.y2 *= 2;
    break;
  case RENDER_STEREO_MODE_SPLIT_VERTICAL:
    screenRect.x2 *= 2;
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }

  return screenRect;
}

bool CWinRenderer::Configure(const VideoPicture &picture, float fps, unsigned int orientation)
{
  m_sourceWidth       = picture.iWidth;
  m_sourceHeight      = picture.iHeight;
  m_renderOrientation = orientation;
  m_fps = fps;
  m_iFlags = GetFlagsChromaPosition(picture.chroma_position)
           | GetFlagsColorMatrix(picture.color_space, picture.iWidth, picture.iHeight)
           | GetFlagsColorPrimaries(picture.color_primaries)
           | GetFlagsStereoMode(picture.stereoMode);
  m_format = picture.videoBuffer->GetFormat();

  // calculate the input frame aspect ratio
  CalculateFrameAspectRatio(picture.iDisplayWidth, picture.iDisplayHeight);
  SetViewMode(m_videoSettings.m_ViewMode);
  // if (picture.hasDisplayMetadata || picture.hasLightMetadata) {
  SetHdrMonitorMode(true);
    // } 
  ManageRenderArea();


  m_renderer.reset(SelectRenderer(picture));
  if (!m_renderer || !m_renderer->Configure(picture, fps, orientation))
  {
    m_renderer.reset();
    return false;
  }

  m_bConfigured = true;
  return true;
}
static bool first = true;

void CWinRenderer::SetHdrMonitorMode(bool enableHDR)
{
    if (first)
    {
        NvAPI_Initialize();
        first = false;
    }

    NvAPI_Status nvStatus = NVAPI_OK;
    NvDisplayHandle hNvDisplay = NULL;

    // get first display handle which should work for all NVAPI calls for all GPUs
    if ((nvStatus = NvAPI_EnumNvidiaDisplayHandle(0, &hNvDisplay)) != NVAPI_OK)
    {
        printf("NvAPI_EnumNvidiaDisplayHandle returned error code %d\r\n", nvStatus);

        return;
    }

    NvU32 gpuCount = 0;
    NvU32 maxDisplayIndex = 0;
    NvPhysicalGpuHandle ahGPU[NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS] = {};

    // get the list of displays connected, populate the dynamic components
    nvStatus = NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs(ahGPU, &gpuCount);

    if (NVAPI_OK != nvStatus)
    {
        printf("NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs returned error code %d\r\n", nvStatus);

        return;
    }

    for (NvU32 i = 0; i < gpuCount; ++i)
    {
        NvU32 displayIdCount = 16;
        NvU32 flags = 0;
        NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS displayIdArray[16] = {};
        displayIdArray[0].version = NV_GPU_DISPLAYIDS_VER;

        nvStatus = NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds(ahGPU, displayIdArray, &displayIdCount, flags);

        if (NVAPI_OK == nvStatus)
        {
            printf("Display count %d\r\n", displayIdCount);

            for (maxDisplayIndex = 0; maxDisplayIndex < displayIdCount; ++maxDisplayIndex)
            {
                printf("Display tested %d\r\n", maxDisplayIndex);

                NV_HDR_CAPABILITIES hdrCapabilities = {};

                hdrCapabilities.version = NV_HDR_CAPABILITIES_VER;

                if (NVAPI_OK == NvAPI_Disp_GetHdrCapabilities(displayIdArray[maxDisplayIndex].displayId, &hdrCapabilities))
                {
                    if (hdrCapabilities.isST2084EotfSupported)
                    {
                        printf("Display %d supports ST2084 EOTF\r\n", maxDisplayIndex);

                        NV_HDR_COLOR_DATA hdrColorData = {};

                        memset(&hdrColorData, 0, sizeof(hdrColorData));

                        hdrColorData.version = NV_HDR_COLOR_DATA_VER;
                        hdrColorData.cmd = NV_HDR_CMD_SET;
                        hdrColorData.static_metadata_descriptor_id = NV_STATIC_METADATA_TYPE_1;

                        hdrColorData.hdrMode = enableHDR ? NV_HDR_MODE_UHDBD : NV_HDR_MODE_OFF;


                        nvStatus = NvAPI_Disp_HdrColorControl(displayIdArray[maxDisplayIndex].displayId, &hdrColorData);

                        if (NVAPI_OK == nvStatus)
                        {
                            printf("NvAPI_Disp_SethdrColorData call has succeeded: ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            NvAPI_ShortString szDesc;
                            NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(nvStatus, szDesc);
                            printf("NvAPI_Disp_HdrColorControl returned %s (%x)\r\n", szDesc, nvStatus);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    NvAPI_ShortString szDesc;
                    NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(nvStatus, szDesc);
                    printf("NvAPI_Disp_GetHdrCapabilities returned %s (%x)\r\n", szDesc, nvStatus);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NvAPI_ShortString szDesc;
            NvAPI_GetErrorMessage(nvStatus, szDesc);
            printf("NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds returned %s (%x)\r\n", szDesc, nvStatus);
        }
    }
  }  

int CWinRenderer::NextBuffer() const
{
  return m_renderer->NextBuffer();
}

void CWinRenderer::AddVideoPicture(const VideoPicture &picture, int index)
{
  m_renderer->AddVideoPicture(picture, index);
}

void CWinRenderer::Update()
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return;

  ManageRenderArea();
  m_renderer->ManageTextures();
}

void CWinRenderer::RenderUpdate(int index, int index2, bool clear, unsigned int flags, unsigned int alpha)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return;

  if (clear)
    CServiceBroker::GetWinSystem()->GetGfxContext().Clear(DX::Windowing()->UseLimitedColor() ? 0x101010 : 0);
  DX::Windowing()->SetAlphaBlendEnable(alpha < 255);

  ManageRenderArea();
  m_renderer->Render(index, index2, DX::Windowing()->GetBackBuffer(), 
                     m_sourceRect, m_destRect, GetScreenRect(), flags);
}

bool CWinRenderer::RenderCapture(CRenderCapture* capture)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return false;

  capture->BeginRender();
  if (capture->GetState() != CAPTURESTATE_FAILED)
  {
    const CRect destRect(0, 0, static_cast<float>(capture->GetWidth()), static_cast<float>(capture->GetHeight()));

    m_renderer->Render(capture->GetTarget(), m_sourceRect, destRect, GetScreenRect());
    capture->EndRender();

    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

void CWinRenderer::SetBufferSize(int numBuffers)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return;

  m_renderer->SetBufferSize(numBuffers);
}

void CWinRenderer::PreInit()
{
  CSingleLock lock(CServiceBroker::GetWinSystem()->GetGfxContext());
  m_bConfigured = false;
  UnInit();
}

void CWinRenderer::UnInit()
{
  CSingleLock lock(CServiceBroker::GetWinSystem()->GetGfxContext());

  m_renderer.reset();
  m_bConfigured = false;
}

bool CWinRenderer::Flush(bool saveBuffers)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return false;

  return m_renderer->Flush(saveBuffers);
}

bool CWinRenderer::Supports(ERENDERFEATURE feature)
{
  if(feature == RENDERFEATURE_BRIGHTNESS)
    return true;

  if(feature == RENDERFEATURE_CONTRAST)
    return true;

  if (feature == RENDERFEATURE_STRETCH         ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_NONLINSTRETCH   ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_ZOOM            ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_VERTICAL_SHIFT  ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_PIXEL_RATIO     ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_ROTATION        ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_POSTPROCESS     ||
      feature == RENDERFEATURE_TONEMAP)
    return true;

  return false;
}

bool CWinRenderer::Supports(ESCALINGMETHOD method)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return false;

  return m_renderer->Supports(method);
}

bool CWinRenderer::WantsDoublePass()
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return false;

  return m_renderer->WantsDoublePass();
}

bool CWinRenderer::ConfigChanged(const VideoPicture& picture)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return true;

  return picture.videoBuffer->GetFormat() != m_format;
}

CRenderInfo CWinRenderer::GetRenderInfo()
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return {};

  return m_renderer->GetRenderInfo();
}

void CWinRenderer::ReleaseBuffer(int idx)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return;

  m_renderer->ReleaseBuffer(idx);
}

bool CWinRenderer::NeedBuffer(int idx)
{
  if (!m_bConfigured)
    return false;

  return m_renderer->NeedBuffer(idx);
}


´´´
```

Comment: You're trying to pass an array of GPU handles to a function that only wants one.  Did you mean `ahGPU[i]`?

Comment: You mean change ahGPU[NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS] to ahGPU[i]?

Comment: No, at the `NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds` call site.

Comment: nvStatus = NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds(ahGPU[i], displayIdArray, &displayIdCount, flags); 
Errors passed!! I don't know if the hdr function is working but all erros are gone! Can you explain to me what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
nvStatus = NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds(ahGPU, displayIdArray, &displayIdCount, flags);
```

to

```
nvStatus = NvAPI_GPU_GetConnectedDisplayIds(ahGPU[i], displayIdArray, &displayIdCount, flags);
```

Thanks to @1201ProgramAlarm